# pthread_mutex_destroy blocks in infinite loop

Tags: iphone, pthreads, posix

I use POSIX threads on iPhone/iPad and when I try to destroy a mutex, pthread_mutex_destroy blocks in infinite loop. I did not find anything about this. It should return an error code...

Do you know something about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that your pthread_mutex_t was locked during the call to pthread_mutex_destroy, as the behavior in that case is undefined.